# JavsScript: How to convert a UTC timestamp to human readable time?

Tags: javascript, utc

How can I convert a UTC timestamp to human readable time - using JavaScript?

For instance, I have this timestamp - `1425356823380`

I would like to convert it to this format,

```
03/03/2015 04:27:03
```

This is how I get the timestamp from,

```
var d = new Date();
var utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `new Date(1425356823380).toLocaleString()` ? Plenty of other methods here if that doesn't suit - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype#Methods

Comment: Use a library like moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is known as an **Epoch Time**. An easy way to retrieve the date is as follows:

```
var d = new Date(1425356823380);
```

The resulting date will be in the format you need.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qekycmyk/4/)

Comment: `new Date(1425356823380)` does the same thing ;)